# Accuracy is 100% but model.predict is totaly wrong! what could be the problem? (Autoencoder NN)

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy, autoencoders, training-error

Its an Autoencoder model that receive 4 different vectors { (1,0,0,0) , (0,1,0,0) , (0,0,1,0) , (0,0,0,1) }
The encoder transforms the vectors to vectors size 2, which get inside an "NLPN channel" which is a channel with nonlinear phase noise, and then goes to the decoder that reconstructs the original vector.
Architecture: 4->50->2->NLPN->2->50->4(Sotmax)
The loss function is mse between the input, and the input ( self.model.fit(self.x, self.x) )
The code is pretty basic: the first cell is just some simple functions defined, then its the autoencoder class, then its the training, and then its the prediction which shows that for each vector 1,0,0,0 and so on, the decoder predict (~0.25,~0.25,~0.25,~0.25) which shows that the NN has no idea what it's doing

CODE:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nFymmEloUSa1yjS7e5CPGsKwqP1HjS57?usp=sharing

Comment: Your loss is supposed to be identical to mine square so why don’t you try using the built-in?

Comment: u mean to use lost fucntion = 'mse'..? it doesn't change anything..

Comment: I have a feeling that its soemthing related to the fact that I created neural network in a Class, and where I predict output - I think it might somehow not using the "trained" net and just create new one.. what do u think? I think I need to use save weights and then load them outside the class or something like that..

Comment: It is really good to start with the simplest model. If you’re gonna be going object oriented than you need to make tests every step of the way and certify every step of the process before you can move forward. Some folks go as far as to say build the tests before you write the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the constructor for a `Dense` layer in keras, that instantiates an object that can perform the computation of a "dense" or "fully connected" layer, along with the model parameters associated with that layer. If you call the constructor multiple times, as you do in your code, multiple independent sets of parameters are created. If you mutate one of those sets, say by training your network, none of the other parameter sets are affected.